# Xbox 360 Kinect use with MS Teams as webcam camera driver runtime recognizing device only as audio

Tags: kinect, webcam, microsoft-teams

So instead of buying another webcam I decided to try out the Xbox 360 Kinect stored away in our storage. I successfully paired it to my cMP 5,1 running OSX Mojave and windows 10 in bootcamp. I bought the adapter to connect the kinect to USB from amazon, $12 ("JETEHO 1 Pc Xbox 360 Kinect Sensor USB AV Adapter"). Now with Kinect for Windows Runtime v1.8 installed, the devices that show up when the Kinect is connected are as follows:
[Kinect for Windows recognizes the kinect as a camera, this is not what Teams recognizes though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UGnH.png)

So the camera there  is recognized by the computer, but my problem is that when I open MS Teams this does not get recognized as one of the devices. The tricky thing is that MS teams recognized the Kinect as an audio device, but I need it to be recognized as a video device.
[MS teams recognized the Kinect as a USB audio device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do9eA.png)

Kinect as a usb audio device can also be seen in the device manager:
[Kinect is recognized as a usb audio device, but I need it to be video as well so I can use it as a webcam in MS Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1zjf.png)

Below is a snip of the MS teams settings not showing the camera as being there: [Settings in MS teams showing no camera detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKGqy.png)

So, I wanted to know could there be something that I am missing, a driver perhaps of some sort? I have the KinectCam.ax file installed as well and registered, again with no change.

I've tried installing the various SDK's from Microsoft website including v1.8 and v2.0 and even tried installing the most recent runtime from Microsoft for Kinect v2.2 with no avail. The machine still doesn't recognize the kinect as a video or camera device in the device controllers and its driving me bonkers! I have OpenNI virtual cam v0.9.5.0 installed and it recognized the Kinect. The SDKs I've installed also recognize the camera from the Kinect but not MS Teams and that is what I was hoping to use as a webcam device. Any solutions I will try at this point. Also, this website proved somewhat useful, but for some reason I am not getting the same results as them.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/using-a-kinect-in-teams/3891a30a-2d4e-4d22-8d92-aa7b3ffd779c
GammalSkinka found the solution by using virtual cam for Teams to recognize the device, but I'm not getting the same results as well as cbscript_chris.
[working with runtime installed, and w/o sdk, but not for me =(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhmLu.png)

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please post it to [Product Support Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels)

Comment: I think this issuse has been solved. I will need to do some more digging in the Support Channel mentioned above.